# How do you write a bytecode file?

Tags: java, jvm, java-bytecode-asm

I'm studying compiler design and I'm trying to make a small language that targets a subset of the JVM bytecode specification.

Much like how Java compiles to Java Bytecode, I want to write a compiler that will take my language and compile it to the same Java Bytecode, so thus can be fed into the JVM.

I already pretty much know the front-end basics of compilation. I can make a lexer and a parser and etc. I know how to derive and check the semantics and all of that.

That part is easy for me. The hard part is the actual code generation. I know, there's probably a lot of tools and even pre-written code generators. But just like I didn't use yacc and etc for my front-end section, I don't want to use tools for my backend just yet.

Especially since my front-end output probably doesn't conform to any standard these tools use anyway.

How would one go about generating a bytecode file once you have the front-end output? I know what java bytecode LOOKS like, but how do you write it out to a new file that can be then fed to the JVM?

Comment: Java VM specification, and use a DataOutputStream.

Comment: You might be interested in my post at https://alblue.bandlem.com/2020/06/bite-sized-bytecode.html which explains how it works. I also have a bytecode emulator linked from there.

Answer (score 2):

you have to know the java `.class` file structure and more details about that, very difficult to write details here. example structure of java class file

```
ClassFile {
    4 bytes        Java Magic Number
    2 bytes        Minor Version
    2 bytes        Major Version
    2 bytes        Size of the constant pool
    * bytes        Numerous bytes making up the constant pool
    2 bytes        This class' access modifiers (Ie. public)
    2 bytes        Index of this class in constant pool
    2 bytes        Index of this class' super class in constant pool
    2 bytes        Number of interfaces
    * bytes        Numerous bytes making up interface definitions
    2 bytes        Number of fields in this class
    * bytes        Numerous bytes making up field definitions
    2 bytes        Number of methods in this class
    * bytes        Numerous bytes making up method definitions
    2 bytes        Attributes count ( meta data for class file )
    * bytes        Numerous bytes making up attribute definitions
}
```

by the way details read from [here](https://medium.com/@davethomas_9528/writing-hello-world-in-java-byte-code-34f75428e0ad)

hope it will help you to know further

Answer (score 0):

You write a byte code file the same as you write any binary file. Here's an example that writes the Java class file "magic number" 0xCAFEBABE to a .class file:

```
try (var fout = new FileOutputStream("A.class")) {
   byte[] bytecode = {(byte) 0xca, (byte) 0xfe, (byte) 0xba, (byte) 0xbe};
   fout.write(bytecode);
}
```

As for what exactly should come after the magic number, how to actually write a Java class with variables and methods etc, that's documented in the JVM specification: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html

You'll find it is very complicated. That's why people usually use libraries that make it easier, such as [ASM](https://asm.ow2.io/) or [Bytebuddy](https://bytebuddy.net/).